# is it possible to create multi websocket client in one html?

Tags: javascript, websocket

This is my code to create multi websocket connection:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>runoob.com</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function WebSocketTest() {
         if ("WebSocket" in window) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
               // open web socket
               new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8070");
               console.log("open" + i + "websocket");
            }
         }
      }
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="sse">
      <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I want to receive message from server,how to write code ? Code like this may share ws variable and not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>runoob.com</title>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function WebSocketTest() {
         if ("WebSocket" in window) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 300; i++) {
               // open web socket
               var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8070");
               console.log("open" + i + "websocket");

               ws.onmessage = function (evt) 
               { 
                 var received_msg = evt.data;
               };
            }
         }
      }
   </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="sse">
      <a href="javascript:WebSocketTest()">Run WebSocket</a>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible (though you would need to change the example code)... but why waste resources?

Comment: I am testing how much websocket connect the server could handle,@Myst

Comment: Most browsers will prevent their JavaScrip engine from being used this way. They will limit the number of available WebSocket connections (the limit was 300 last time I tested Chrome)... The server will probably be able to handle many more WebSocket clients then a browser will be willing to open.

Comment: @Myst perhaps, but you can simply run multiple browsers at a time to use more clients

Comment: @Dolphin "*I am testing how much websocket connect the server could handle*" - that is something that is better handled in an application rather than in a web browser. Write a program in whatever language you want that has a WebSocket library available for it, and then you can create and manage as many WebSocket client connections as you want.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Can you?

Comment: @Myst can I what?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - can you really open more browsers to overcome the connection limit? Because I doubt you could comfortably do that. Writing the script in a non-browser environment is much more effective.

Comment: @Myst "*can you really open more browsers to overcome the connection limit?*" - Why not? Why would you think otherwise? They are just TCP connections like any other. They are not limited by the OS, only by the browser. So if a browser limits the number of WebSocket clients it creates to, say, 300 per process, then running X browser processes should be able to create up to X*300 clients total, unless the browser processes talk to each other to share a single limit. But running different types of browsers together can easily overcome that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau , try it. You’ll notice browsers are often multi-process beasts with shared memory and IPC mechanisms. They can be harder to isolate than one might assume. More likely then not, they will enforce the same limits across multiple processes. But maybe I’m wrong. I just don’t think it’s as easy as the theory suggests.

Comment: @Myst which is why I suggested running multiple *different* browsers together.  Sure, multiple Chromes may talk to either other, but they won't talk to FireFox, and vice versa, for instance. But this is really a moot issue, since this is not the best way to load-test a server anyway.

Comment: I obey your suggestion and test complete smoothly.Thank you!The Chromes limit is 250,I must open greater than 20 different browsers to test,the code client could keep 1355,open 4 or 5 enough.JMeter could not keep the websocket connection. @RemyLebeau

Answer (score 0):

Write the code like this,but the Chrome limit the websocket connection less than 250 in my test:

```
      function newcon(i) {
         var ws = new WebSocket("wss://ws.example.com");
         console.log("open" + i + "websocket");
         ws.onopen = function () {
            ws.send("client " + i + " send message");
         };

         ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
            var received_msg = evt.data;
         };

         ws.onclose = function () {
            console.log("closed");
         };
      }
```

Invoke the function:

```
     function WebSocketTest() {
         if ("WebSocket" in window) {
            for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
               newcon(i);
            }
         }
      }
```